# Is it useful to compute R Squared for regression trees?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, model-selection, cart, validation

I have a regression tree and want to validate the peformance. The first measure I have is the mse to find which model is the best. After that I want to check if the model peforms better then an average baseline model. So I computed the R-Squared.

Is this prcodeure right or  is R-Squared not useful as a preformance measure for regression trees?

Comment: Why not use the same metric (MSE) to compare your tree with the baseline?

Comment: @arinarmo because i want to have two performances measure in my thesis and not only one :D. It's a suggestions from my prof so i found the r-squared as the second measure.

Comment: What's your baseline? If it is the mean then pseudo-R2 can be definitely interpreted as the improvement compared to it.

Comment: yes its the mean